# Extracting data from multiple raster layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, extract, weather

I have a raster layer containing climatic monthly data:

- rainfall
- maximum and minimum temperatures

There is one layer for each variable and month.

I want to extract the average and maximum values for all of these layers into an Excel sheet.

Is there a way to do this without having to manually extract each value for every raster layer?